# How do I .htaccess redirect a url to include a folder and subfolder after the domain and before the filename?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

So I'm trying to write an .htaccess line that redirects urls to the url including the category and subcategory. The filename repeats with a date on the end, and I don't want to disrupt other filenames coming after the domain.

```
https://example.com/filename-Sep-30 

https://example.com/filename-Oct-01

https://example.com/filename-Oct-02 

https://example.com/filename-Oct-03
```

to

```
https://example.com/folder/subfolder/filename-Sep-30

https://example.com/folder/subfolder/filename-Oct-01

https://example.com/folder/subfolder/filename-Oct-02

https://example.com/folder/subfolder/filename-Oct-03
```

without affecting https://example.com/anotherfilename

I tried

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
ReWriteRule ^/filename(.*)$ https://example.com/folder/subfolder [END,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

But it doesn't garner even a response from the page when loaded.

I changed the link structure for my site on wordpress, adding categories and sub categories and now the search engine is sending traffic to the old pages with 404 erors.

I thought Wordpress would automatically redirect the pages but that is not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(filename-[a-zA-Z]+)(-[0-9]+)$  folder/subfolder/$1$2 [R=301,L,NE]
```